# Multidimensional key array push

Tags: php, arrays

What I have is:

```
<?php

$keys = array('a', 'b', 'c', ..., ...);
$value = 'blah';

?>
```

What I want to achieve is:

```
<?php

$someArr['a']['b']['c'][...][...] = $value;

?>
```

What would be the smartest way to achieve this?

// EDIT

I do not know how many elements there's in $keys, that's why I added dots in there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This asks for recursion:

```
<?php
function array_md_push($keys, &$pushto, $value) {
    if ($keys == array()) {                          // no keys left - put value
        $pushto = $value;
    } else {                                         // keys left - recursion!
        $key = array_shift($keys);                   // take the first element
        array_md_push($keys, $pushto[$key], $value); // call with one key less
    }
}

$keys = array('a', 'b', 'c');
$value = 'blah';
$pushto = array();

array_md_push($keys, $pushto, $value);

var_dump($pushto);
```

> Result:
>
> ```
> array(1) {
>   ["a"]=>
>   array(1) {
>     ["b"]=>
>     array(1) {
>       ["c"]=>
>       string(4) "blah"
>     }
>   }
> }
> ```

`array_md_push()` takes the keys as the first argument, the array to push the value to as the second, and the value as the third. If the keys array is empty, it just stores the value in the array to push to. If not, it calls itself, with one key less, and `$pushto` expanded to that key.